# Avoiding for loop in multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

So I have a 3D-array:

```
>>> img_data.shape
(182, 218, 182)
```

My idea is to replace every value equals to 0 with 255. I tried:

```
new_img = np.zeros(img_range)
print(new_img.shape)
for i in range(img_range[0]):
    for j in range(img_range[1]):
        for k in range(img_range[2]):
            print "%s %s %s" % (i, j, k )
            if img_data[i][j][k] == 0:
                new_img[i][j][k] = 2
            else:
                new_img[i][j][k] = img_data[i][j][k]
```

But this take forever, most likely because Python is dynamic and may be doing something in the backgrouns.

Any ideas on how to improve this?
Thanks, 
Rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write your own loop.
You can access all the elements respecting one or more conditions using the square brackets `[]`. Check the [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

Example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10, 10, 10))
a[a == 0] = -100
```